# Solving coupled differential equations with unknown constants

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to obtain exact solutions of these types of coupled differential equations directly in Mathematica

```
x'[t]=-I a x[t] + I \Sqrt[2] b y[t]
y'[t]=I \Sqrt[2] b x[t] + I \Sqrt[2] b z[t]
z'[t]=I \sqrt[2] b y[t] - I a z[t]
```

with initial conditions `x[0]=1` and `y[0]=z[0]=0` ?

**Note:** a,b are real constants

Comment: What happens when you feed them into `DSolve[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equations use `Equal` (`==`) vice `Set` (`=`)

```
eqns = {x'[t] == -I a x[t] + I Sqrt[2] b y[t],
   y'[t] == I Sqrt[2] b x[t] + I Sqrt[2] b z[t],
   z'[t] == I Sqrt[2] b y[t] - I a z[t],
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == z[0] == 0};

soln = DSolve[eqns, {x, y, z}, t][[1]] // FullSimplify

{x -> Function[{t}, 
       (4*b^2*E^((-I)*a*t - (1/2)*I*
                   (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                   t)*(a^2*E^(I*a*t) + 
               16*b^2*E^(I*a*t) + 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
                 E^(I*a*t) + 2*a^2*
                 E^((1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                           a^2 + 16*b^2])*t) + 
               32*b^2*E^((1/2)*I*
                      (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                      t) + a^2*E^(I*a*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(-a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t) + 
               16*b^2*E^(I*a*t + (1/2)*I*
                        (-a + Sqrt[a^2 + 
                             16*b^2])*t + (1/2)*I*
                        (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                        t) - a*Sqrt[a^2 + 
                     16*b^2]*E^(I*a*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(-a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t)))/
         ((a^2 + 16*b^2 - 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
            (a^2 + 16*b^2 + 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]))], 
   y -> Function[{t}, 
       -((16*Sqrt[2]*b^3*Sqrt[
                   a^2 + 16*b^2]*(-1 + 
                    E^((1/2)*I*(-a + Sqrt[
                              a^2 + 16*b^2])*t + 
                         (1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                              a^2 + 16*b^2])*t)))/
              E^((1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                        a^2 + 16*b^2])*t)/
            ((-a^2 - 16*b^2 + 
                  a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
               (a^2 + 16*b^2 + 
                  a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])))], 
   z -> Function[{t}, 
       (4*b^2*E^((-I)*a*t - (1/2)*I*
                   (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                   t)*(a^2*E^(I*a*t) + 
               16*b^2*E^(I*a*t) + 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]*
                 E^(I*a*t) - 2*a^2*
                 E^((1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                           a^2 + 16*b^2])*t) - 
               32*b^2*E^((1/2)*I*
                      (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                      t) + a^2*E^(I*a*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(-a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t) + 
               16*b^2*E^(I*a*t + (1/2)*I*
                        (-a + Sqrt[a^2 + 
                             16*b^2])*t + (1/2)*I*
                        (a + Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
                        t) - a*Sqrt[a^2 + 
                     16*b^2]*E^(I*a*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(-a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t + 
                      (1/2)*I*(a + Sqrt[
                            a^2 + 16*b^2])*t)))/
         ((a^2 + 16*b^2 - 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2])*
            (a^2 + 16*b^2 + 
               a*Sqrt[a^2 + 16*b^2]))]}
```

Verifyng that the solution satisfies the equations and initial conditions

```
And @@ ((eqns /. soln) // Simplify)

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: thanx. i'm srry, but, i'm getting `Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {(x^\[Prime])[t]==-I a x[t]+I Sqrt[2] b y[t],(y^\[Prime])[t]==I Sqrt[2] b x[t]+I Sqrt[2] b z[t],True,x[0]==1,y[0]==z[0]==0}. >>`. am i inputting it wrong ?

Comment: @ss1729, because of your previous definitions with `Set=`  all equations evaluate to `True`; so you need to re-start the kernel to clear all previously defined symbols.

Answer (score 3):

```
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == -I a x[t] + I Sqrt[2] b y[t],
   y'[t] == I Sqrt[2] b x[t] + I Sqrt[2] b z[t],
   z'[t] == I Sqrt[2] b y[t] - I a z[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
   z[0] == 0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 20}, {a, b}]

Plot[Through[{Re, Im}@#] & /@ {x[.1, .5][t], y[.1, .5][t], 
    z[.1, .5][t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> (Style[#, Italic, 16] & /@ {"Re[x[.1,.5][t]", 
     "Im[x[.1,.5][t]", "Re[y[.1,.5][t]", "Im[y[.1,.5][t]", 
     "Re[z[.1,.5][t]", "Im[z[.1,.5][t]"})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 On my Mac with v10.4.1 the `PlotLegends` don't show properly unless I use `Evaluate` with the first argument to `Plot`. The option `Evaluated -> True` doesn't work with `Plot` on later versions.

Comment: @BobHanlon, right; same on v9 on Windows 10 if i use `"Expressions"` as the setting for `PlotLegends`